# Filtering pandas dataframe for a steady speed condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

Below is a sample dataframe which is similar to mine except the one I am working on has 200,000 data points.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame([
        [10.07,5], [10.24,5], [12.85,5], [11.85,5],
        [11.10,5], [14.56,5], [14.43,5], [14.85,5],
        [14.95,5], [10.41,5], [15.20,5], [15.47,5],
        [15.40,5], [15.31,5], [15.43,5], [15.65,5]
    ], columns=['speed','delta_t'])
df

    speed  delta_t
0   10.07        5
1   10.24        5
2   12.85        5
3   11.85        5
4   11.10        5
5   14.56        5
6   14.43        5
7   14.85        5
8   14.95        5
9   10.41        5
10  15.20        5
11  15.47        5
12  15.40        5
13  15.31        5
14  15.43        5
15  15.65        5
```

---

```
std_dev = df.iloc[0:3,0].std()  # this will give 1.55
print(std_dev)
```

I have 2 columns, 'Speed' and 'Delta_T'. Delta_T is the difference in time between subsequent rows in my actual data (it has date and time). The operating speed keeps varying and what I want to achieve is to filter out all data points where the speed is nearly steady, say by filtering for a standard deviations of < 0.5 and Delta_T >=15 min. For example, if we start with the first speed, the code should be able to keep jumping to the next speeds, keep calculating the standard deviation and if it less than 0.5 and it delta_T sums up to 30 min and more I should be copy that data into a new dataframe. 
So for this dataframe I will be left with index 5 to 8 and 10 to15.

Is this possible? Could you please give me some suggestion on how to do it? Sorry I am stuck. It seems to complicated to me.

Thank you.

Best Regards Arun

Comment: Can you post your desired data set?

Comment: Thank you. It will look like this. df1=pd.DataFrame([[14.56,5],[14.43,5],[14.85,5],[14.95,5],[15.2,5],[15.47,5],[15.4,5],[15.31,5],[15.43,5],[15.65,5]],columns=['speed','delta_t']). I just created another dataframe from the original data to get my desired. Ideally, the code should create a newone based on the std and time criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let use `rolling`,`shift` and `std`:

Calculate the rolling std for a window of 3, the find those stds less than 0.5 and use shift(-2) to get the values at the start of the window where std was less than 0.5.  Using boolean indexing with `|`(or) we can get the entire steady state range.

```
df_std = df['speed'].rolling(3).std()
df_ss = df[(df_std < 0.5) | (df_std < 0.5).shift(-2)]
df_ss
```

Output:

```
    speed  delta_t
5   14.56        5
6   14.43        5
7   14.85        5
8   14.95        5
10  15.20        5
11  15.47        5
12  15.40        5
13  15.31        5
14  15.43        5
15  15.65        5
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your reply. This is working for the data I gave you. But if I need to do it for a time criteria of greater than 20 min it would not right?  I tried doing rolling 4 and changing shift but it would not work.I want to be able to change the delta T criteria.

Comment: I dont see why not.  Lets test with the different data set.  4 rolling and shift -3 should work the same.